# Can I run a specific android app in browser through emulator using node js server?

Tags: android, node.js, browser

I want to run an app inside the emulator in the browser. Is it possible? Then how can I transfer data into that emulator?

Comment: What emulator is running in the browser? Do you mean an Android emulator implemented in JavaScript? Does any such thing exist?

Comment: Yes, an android emulator should be implemented in javaScript, Seems  i don't think such a thing exist. I want to know is there anything exists? Otherwise is there any option to run andy emulaor [link](http://www.andyroid.net/) in my browser?